# 'Relation already exists' error in pgrouting

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis, pgadmin, pgrouting

I am creating a TABLE with the following sql:

```
-- Table: buildings

-- DROP TABLE buildings;

CREATE TABLE buildings
(

osm_id integer NOT NULL,

"name" character varying(255),

"type" character varying(255),

"geometry" geometry,

CONSTRAINT enforce_dims_geometry CHECK (st_ndims(geometry) = 2)

)

WITH (

OIDS=FALSE

);

ALTER TABLE buildings OWNER TO "user";
```

*And Afterwards, trying to fill the table with data from another table with this:*

```
    SELECT osm_id, way

INTO buildings

FROM planet_osm_polygon

WHERE building='yes'
```

*And I get the following error:*

ERROR:  relation "buildings" already exists

*** *Error* *****

ERROR: relation "buildings" already exists
SQL state: 42P07

Any idea as to why this might be the case? I'm new to pgrouting and trying to figure out how to proceed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your command

```
SELECT osm_id, way

INTO buildings

FROM planet_osm_polygon

WHERE building='yes'
```

is creating table buildings which has been already created, that's why your getting this error. Please refer this [link](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/04/30/sql-server-ctas-create-table-as-select-what-is-ctas/) for more information

Comment: Thanks a lot! was a simple problem, but extremely important. Cheers!